# ¿Cómo imprimir valores dinámicos en un Div?

Tags: jquery, json

Función Jquery

```
 $.ajax({
              data: parametros,
                  type:"POST",
                  url:"cUrl.php",
                  dataType : "JSON",
                  success: function(res){
                      for (var i in res) 
                     {
                       $('#lol').html("<li>"+ res[i].Nombre+ "</li>");
                        console.log(res[i].Nombre );
                     }

                  }
              });
```

Los valores del Json son 4, pero en la etiqueda "lol", solo me imprime uno de esos valores, pero en el console.log si aparecen todos. Saben a que se deba eso?

ésto imprime en el console.log

```
Hotel del Portal San Miguel de Allende
2xfunciones.js?var=1:20 Real de Minas San Miguel de Allende
xfunciones.js?var=1:20 Misión San Miguel de Allende
xfunciones.js?var=1:20 Hotel Arcada San Miguel
```

Pero en el div solo parece el último

Comment: Saludos; prueba con **$('#lol').html($('#lol').html() + "<br /><li>"+ res[i].Nombre+ "</li>");** pero primero antes del *for* usa **$('#lol').html("")**. La razón que es a **lol** solo estas dejando el valor actual de ciclo, no estas "respaldando" el valor anterior; otra es usar *append* pero prueba con lo primero sino, checa *append*. Suerte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia `.html()` por `.append()` debido a que con `.html()` lo que hace es reemplazar todo lo que contenga el elemento seleccionado y con `.append()` vas concatenando elementos

por lo tanto deberia quedarte de esta forma

```
 $.ajax({
  data: parametros,
  type:"POST",
  url:"cUrl.php",
  dataType : "JSON",
  success: function(res){
    for (var i in res) 
    {
      $('#lol').append("<li>"+ res[i].Nombre+ "</li>");
      console.log(res[i].Nombre );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, sin duda la solución